# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am building a hotel management application using laravel. I am trying to create the tables 'reservations' in laravel but when I run the 'migrate:fresh' command, I get the following: error "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed". Can anyone tell what do you mean by this error?

[View Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qud7V.jpg)

```
public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('room_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('title')->unique();
                $table->string('slug')->unique();
                $table->string('short_code')->unique();
                $table->longText('description')->nullable();
                $table->integer('base_capacity')->default(0);
                $table->integer('higher_capacity')->default(0);
                $table->boolean('extra_bed')->default(0);
                $table->integer('kids_capacity')->default(0);
                $table->float('base_price',8,2)->default(0);
                $table->float('additional_person_price',8,2)->default(0);
                $table->float('extra_bed_price',8,2)->default(0);
                $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
                $table->softDeletes();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }

public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');

            $table->string('usertype')->default('user');
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->nullable();
            $table->date('dob')->nullable();
            $table->longText('address')->nullable();
            $table->enum('sex',['M','F','O'])->default('M');
            $table->string('picture')->nullable();
            $table->string('id_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('id_number')->nullable();
            $table->string('id_card_image_front')->nullable();
            $table->string('id_card_image_back')->nullable();
            $table->string('company_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('gst_no')->nullable();
            $table->text('remarks')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('vip')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }




public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('uid')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('date');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('room_type_id');
            $table->integer('adults')->default(1);
            $table->integer('kids')->default(0);
            $table->date('check_in');
            $table->date('check_out');
            $table->integer('number_of_room')->default(1);
            $table->enum('status',['PENDING','CANCEL','SUCCESS'])->default('PENDING');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('room_type_id')->references('id')->on('room_types')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

**Error message**

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `hotelplex`.`reservations` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `reservations` add constraint `reservations_reservations_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`reservations_user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

          at C:\xampp\htdocs\hotelplex\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
            665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
            666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
            667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
            668|         catch (Exception $e) {
          > 669|             throw new QueryException(
            670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
            671|             );
            672|         }
            673| 

          1   C:\xampp\htdocs\hotelplex\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:463
              PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `hotelplex`.`reservations` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

          2   C:\xampp\htdocs\hotelplex\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:463
              PDOStatement::execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Laravel6**

`Laravel6` does not have any method `id()` to create `id` in a table. `Laravel7` does.. I tried creating `id` using `$table->id()` using `Laravel6` and got the below error.

It seems you posted wrong error or you have already created `id` manually in your tables.

You can use `bigIncrements`,`bigInteger`, `increments`,`integer` etc.

You can find all available methods [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-columns)

**Laravel7**

As per `Laravel7` `$table->id()` is alias of Alias of `$table->bigIncrements('id')` i.e. `unsigned big integer`.

To create `Foreign key` the data type for the `child column` must match the `parent column` exactly.

Since `users.id` and `room_types.id` is a `bigIncrements` then `reservations.user_id` and `reservations.room_type_id` also needs to be an `unsignedbigInteger`, not a `unsignedInteger`.

So to make it work

**change**

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id'); 
$table->unsignedInteger('room_type_id');
```

**to**

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('room_type_id');
```

Like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('uid')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('date');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('room_type_id');
            $table->integer('adults')->default(1);
            $table->integer('kids')->default(0);
            $table->date('check_in');
            $table->date('check_out');
            $table->integer('number_of_room')->default(1);
            $table->enum('status',['PENDING','CANCEL','SUCCESS'])->default('PENDING');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('room_type_id')->references('id')->on('room_types')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#creating-columns

[image]

Comment: Per the docs it does as of 6 `$table->id(); Alias of $table->bigIncrements('id')` https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#columns

Comment: $table->id(); is available in laravel 6

Comment: @jeremykenedy  it is not available in Laravel6 it is available in Laravel7

Comment: @HarshithVA  it is not available in Laravel6 it is available in Laravel7 –

Comment: I am really sorry you are right it's available in laravel 7.

Comment: @HarshithVA and as per Laravel7 id is alias of `biginteger` so just change `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')` to `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')` same for `room_type_id` it will work

Answer (score 0):

The `->onDelete('cascade');` should be on the relationships creation part.

Change the to:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Structure
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('uid')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('date');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('room_type_id');
        $table->integer('adults')->default(1);
        $table->integer('kids')->default(0);
        $table->date('check_in');
        $table->date('check_out');
        $table->integer('number_of_room')->default(1);
        $table->enum('status',['PENDING','CANCEL','SUCCESS'])->default('PENDING');
        $table->timestamps();

        // Relationships
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('room_type_id')->references('id')->on('room_types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be of data type mismatching for **user_id and room_type_id**

$table->id(); alias of  Alias of $table->bigIncrements('id');

https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#columns

So, you need foreign `user_id` and `room_type_id` column on reservations like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Structure
        $table->id();
        ...
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('room_type_id');
        ...
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
         $table->foreign('room_type_id')->references('id')->on('room_types')->onDelete('cascade');
            ...
         })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

on laravel 8, you can use this

```
$table->id();
....
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');            
$table->unsignedBigInteger('room_type_id');
...
$table->timestamps();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('restrict');
$table->foreign('room_type_id')->references('id')->on('room_types')->onDelete('restrict');
```